# Sporadically SqlDataReader doesn't fill DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2014-express

We've got some code to manage `SQL`-Connections. The class keeps the connection open for faster access to the database. Last week i recognized, that sporadically a `DataTable` is created but not filled with any Data. It happens when the software stays unused for some time. I could catched it in a Debug-Session but after i run the part of code for a second time, it returned a filled table like expected.

Our customer uses the same software on other machines since some months and didn't got this problem yet. Only on a new selled system this happens. But its the same SQL-Server and Databank. Has anyone an Idea why? Is there any timeout or something like this?

Thank you in advance

```
public class DBEncaps
{
    public SqlConnection oSqlDbConnection = null;

    public void OpenDb (string _sOpenString )
    {
        this.oSqlDbConnection = new SqlConnection(this.sConnectionString);
        this.oSqlDbConnection.Open();
    }

    public DataTable GetTable (string _sSql, string _sTableName)
    {
        DataTable oTable = null;
        SqlCommand oSqlDbCmd = new SqlCommand(_sSql, this.oSqlDbConnection);
        SqlDataAdapter oSqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(oSqlDbCmd);
        oSqlAdapter.Fill(oTable);
    }
}

void CallingFunction()
{
    DBEncaps encap = new DBEncaps();
    encap.OpenDb ("Server=127.0.0.1; Database=foo; Trusted_Connection=yes");
    Datatable someTable = encap.GetTable("SELECT * FROM dbo.bar");
}
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? I always close the connection once I'm done with it. .NET has its own internal connection pooling.

Comment: No i don't get any Exception. I've read something with the connection-pooling today. But the code is older. Hence we develop for realtime-systems (milliseconds are crucial) and had bad experiences with DB-connections in C++, this is the result.